# Does the formulation of a quantum theory of gravity depend on the interpretation you give to quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity

Does the formulation of a quantum theory of gravity depend on the interpretation you give to quantum mechanics?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The interpretations of Quantum Mechanics with the Kopenhagen- and the Many-Worlds-Interpretation as the most prominent ones rely on its abstract mathematical formalism. They agree on subjects like quantum state, wave function etc. They disagree on things like the collapse of the wave function and the concept of reality.

Any theory of Quantum Gravity based on an interpretation of QM would be an interpratation itself. If verified however experimentally it had the potenial to confirm an interpretation of QM.

But it seems much more likely that a future QG will be founded strictly on the formalism of QG.

Answer (score 0):

No. Interpretations of quantum mechanics are strictly metaphysical, i.e. they exist in your head. Your head isn't very special.